# Different data types than return value in function?

Tags: c++

Ok I am a bit confused here on a program i made for school. The program executes and i get my desired results but i just think something could be better. In my `findLowest()` function it has an `int` return. Well the data types that i am passing into it in the arguments are `double`. Can a function with one return type have different data type arguments? Or shall i say is there a neater way to do this, maybe casting? I would not have a problem but find lowest needs to be called by `calcAverage()` which leaves me stumped because if i changed the data members than obviously the right data would not be passed to and from each function. Here is the code snippet from the program, thanks for any ideas in advance, if need be it can always be left as is, it works.

```
//function averages input test scores
void calcAverage(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{   
    //call to findLowest() function to decide which score to omit

        double lowest = findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5); 

        double average = ((score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5) - lowest) / 4;

        cout << "Average is: " << average << endl;

}

//determines which input score is lowest 
int findLowest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{

    double low = score1;    

    if(score2 < low)
        low = score2;
    if(score3 < low)
            low = score3;
    if(score4 < low)
        low = score4;
    if(score5 < low)
        low = score5;

    cout << "Lowest score is: " << low << endl;


return low;
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about arrays/vectors yet?  That score1, score2, etc., is going to reach sanity limits quickly.

Comment: @Duck i wish i could use them but they are next chapter and i am not permitted to use them

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you change the return type of findLowest to double?

Answer (score 2):

In the body of `findLowest` function you define `double low` but you return it as `int` so that you can assign it to `double` again.

Change type of this return value from `int` to `double` and everything will be fine.

*"Can a function with one return type have different data type arguments?"*
Of course it can. Type of return value is not necessarily related to types of arguments.

*"The issue is in the book that states the problem it says to use a function `int findLowest`"*
Maybe author of this book wanted you to do something like this:

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
...
int findLowest(vector<double>& v)
{
    int lowest = -1;
    double lowestValue = numeric_limits<double>::max();
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (v[i] < lowestValue)
        {
            lowestValue = v[i];
            lowest = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Lowest score is: " << lowestValue << " at index: " << lowest << endl;
    return lowest;
}
...
    // in calcAverage:
    vector<double> args;
    args.resize(5);
    args[0] = score1; args[1] = score2; args[2] = score3; args[3] = score4; args[4] = score5;

    int lowest = findLowest(args);
    args[lowest] = 0;
    double average = (args[0] + args[1] + args[2] + args[3] + args[4]) / 4;
```

Comment: Thats what i am confused on and my suspicions were correct hence my question. The issue is in the book that states the problem it says to us a function int findLowest. Therefor i am not sure it can be changed. Problem is it kind of HAS to be changed since i am dealing with doubles not ints

Comment: @Gmenfan83 Casting isn't gonna help you. Even if you cast inside your function but return an int, it's gonna return an "int" so there is a chance of data loss unless you change the return type.

Comment: @Gmenfan83: Check my answer now. It shows possible solution now.

Comment: @LihO thank you so much but i cannot use vecors or arrays in this program as of yet.

Comment: @Gmenfan83: You will have to write more code without vector / array. But at least you get the idea that I have pointed out ;)

Comment: @LihO yup! I wish i could, things would be so much easier, the assignment states not to though :(

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can. You can pass `foo` types in and return a `bar` type.

In your example though, you need to be aware of one thing. When you assign values of `double` to an `int` type, you truncate them. So you lose precision. If you pass in `0.254` in, you might get `0` out. This is probably not what the callee expects.

I would change `findLowest` so that it returns a `double`, it's best to stick to the right type as long as you can.

Depending on the requirements, an even better solution might be to return an `int` that signifies which of the five numbers were lower. So if you call `findLowest(2.3, 4, 0, 9, 6)` it would return 2. `findLowest(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) = 0` etc.

Comment: I just changed the return to double. I am sure it is understandable by my professor when dealing with doubles not int. I should not get penalized for trying to neaten things up!